# Infinite product discreteness

Tags: general-topology

Let X be the infinite (Countably infinite) product of {0,1} (with the discrete topology and X the product topology.

Is X discrete? I want to say yes since each factor has the discrete topology but in the product topology almost all the factors in a basis elements are represented by R’s. So I’m not really sure.
We can also perhaps try to show that all the singletons are open. But what is a singleton in this space (a product of singletons?)
Could we also show that every point point is not a limit point?

Is X Hausdorff?

Comment: The product space is not discrete, the singletons - which are the infinite binary sequences - are not open. And yes, $X$ is Hausdorff.

Comment: What do you mean by “product of {0,1}”?

Comment: Look at the answer provided. He explains it better than I could

Answer (score 5):

Each point of the product is in effect a sequence of zeroes and ones, say $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$, where each $x_n\in\{0,1\}$. A singleton in the product is a set containing exactly one of those sequences. The product is definitely not discrete; in fact it is homeomorphic to the [middle-thirds Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set#Construction_and_formula_of_the_ternary_set) and has no isolated points at all.

There are several ways to see that it isn’t discrete. If you know the Tikhonov theorem, you know that the arbitrary product of compact spaces is compact. $\{0,1\}$ with the discrete topology is compact, so the product $\{0,1\}^{\Bbb N}$ is compact. It is also clearly infinite, and a discrete space is compact if and only if it is finite, so this product cannot be discrete.

Alternatively, it’s not hard to show that the basic open sets in the product are all infinite. Let $F=\{n_1,\ldots,n_m\}$ be a finite subset of $\Bbb N$, and for $k=1,\ldots,n$ let $x_k\in\{0,1\}$. Then

$$V=\left\{\langle y_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle\in\{0,1\}^{\Bbb N}:y_{n_k}=x_k\text{ for }k=1,\ldots,n\right\}$$

is a basic open set in the product, and the collection of all such sets is a base for the product topology. Clearly $V$ is infinite, since it imposes no restriction on any coordinates of its elements except the ones in $F$. (In fact $V$ is homeomorphic to the whole product.) Since every non-empty open set must contain one of these basic open sets, every non-empty open set must be infinite, and no singleton can be open.

Comment: When you say clearly infinite do you mean that it’s an infinite Cartesian product or that it’s a sequence and thus indexed by the naturals and thus infinite? 

You said singleton in the product is a set containing exactly one of those sequences. What is a set Which contains 2 or 10 of those sequences look like? Each sequence is an element Of the set so is a singleton just a single infinite sequence. Where are the rest? In which set? What is an open set here and how would it look differently if we had another topology.

Comment: The second paragraph is great and I understand it. Third paragraph is very confusing. 
How would we show Hausdorffness

Comment: @Jama: $V$ isn’t a sequence; it’s a set of sequences. Suppose, for instance, that $n=3$, and $n_0,n_1$, $n_2$ are $0,1$, and $2$, respectively, $x_0=1$, $x_1=0$, and $x_2=1$. Then $V$ contains every infinite binary sequence $\langle y_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ such that $y_0=1$, $y_1=0$, and $y_2=1$. In other words, it contains every infinite binary sequence that begins $\langle 1,0,1,\ldots\rangle$, and there are clearly infinitely many different sequences of that form.

Comment: @Jama: To show that the space is Hausdorff, note that if $x=\langle x_k:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ and $y=\langle y_k:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$, and $x\ne y$, then there is an $k_0\in\Bbb N$ such that $x_{k_0}\ne y_{k_0}$. You can separate them with sets of the form $V$ in my answer with $n=1$, in fact, if you let $n_1=k_0$. If $\langle z_k:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is any point in the space, $z_{k_0}$ must agree with exactly one of $x_{k_0}$ and $y_{k_0}$.

Comment: Oh interesting. The n_k’s can be at anyplace and not necessarily restricted the k-th position. So what does n_0 stand for?

Comment: Oh interesting. The n_k’s can be at anyplace and not necessarily restricted the k-th position. So what does n_0 stand for? 

Also why do the open sets have that form? How are we using the discrete topology here and why is F finite?

Also these sequences are uncountable right? How is ir homeomorphic to the middle third cantor set? (Maybe topic for different day)